# Perf stack trace is missing __libc_start_main for some processes

Tags: linux, x86-64, glibc, perf, backtrace

I have a C++ program compiled with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`. I run the same program in two processes and use `perf record -p 24509,24470 -F 977 --call-graph fp -- sleep 120` then `perf script` to get stack traces.

What I found is that  all stack traces from 24509 have `main | __libc_start_main` at the bottom but stack traces from 24470 only have `main`.

My question is why perf stack trace  doesn't have __libc_start_main for one process but have it for the other process even though they are running the same program.

My perf version is `3.10.0-514.36.5.el7.x86_64.debug`.

Comment: Are the two processes both started from the exact same executable, or different builds of it?  Are they started with the same options and environment variables?  Is this repeatable if you restart the processes and run `perf record` again?  Or even if you run `perf record` again *without* restarting them?

Comment: Hi @PeterCordes, those two processes are started from the exact same executable. The only difference is that they log to different log files. Also I restarted the process that's missing `__libc_start_main` and `__libc_start_main` appears after restart. If I don't restart, the process is consistently missing `__libc_start_main`.

Comment: If you try repeated restarts, is it sometimes missing `__libc_start_main`?  Or was that a one-off that you can't repeat at all?  Or maybe after running for a long time, something gets overwritten on the stack and the info is lost?  And BTW, command line args and the environment are on the stack on process entry, but they're above the stack frames that lead to `__libc_start_main` so should have no impact.

Comment: Have you upgraded your system `libc.so.6` after starting the original process?  Maybe `perf` is using stack-unwind metadata from the file of that name in the filesystem, but the libc the process still has mapped has different symbol addresses so its `.eh_frame` addresses don't match.

Comment: Hi @PeterCordes, you are right. I realized that after running the process for a long time, `__libc_start_main` may disappear. That's why I can always see `__libc_start_main` if I immediately run `perf record` after restarting the process. So my question is why the stack gets overwritten if the process runs for a long time.

Comment: Are you sure it's because the stack was overwritten, and not because of a libc upgrade or something?  Have you tried taking a coredump of the process to inspect and see what's going on?  It seems unlikely that the stack could get modified unless there's a buffer overflow in something that `main`  allocates, or something weird.  Maybe execution returns to main after running long enough and something happens that hasn't happened yet in your fresh processes?

Comment: Hi @PeterCordes, no, I'm not sure. Actually, I don't know why that happens. Let me take a coredump and check libc. Maybe I can find something. Thanks!